# Testing render props component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

If I have a render prop component like so:

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <Loader loading={false}>
                {() =>
                    <SomeChildComponent />
               }
    }
}
```

How can I unit test it?

```
test('should output child component',  => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ParentComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(SomeChildComponent).length).to.be(1);
}
```

Fails - If I test for the Loader component instead - the test passes:

```
  expect(wrapper.find(Loader).length).to.be(1);
```

How can I test that SomeChildComponent is output?

Comment: test `<Loader />`, not `<ParentComponent />`

Comment: I need to test that ParentComponent outputs SomeChildComponent though. I've already tested loader separately but I still need to unit test ParentComponent.

Comment: This sort of answers the question...https://medium.com/@dferber90/test-a-render-prop-6a44e02f4c39

Comment: try `mount` instead of `shallow`, that will render the children

Comment: `render()` method seems to miss the `return` statement, also `Loader` seems to not closed.

Answer (score 6):

Your inner function `() =><SomeChildComponent />` never executed, so your test says the truth that `SomeChildComponent` does not exists. You just need to call it (notice extra brackets):

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<Loader loading={false}>
            { (() =><SomeChildComponent />)()}
        </Loader>);
    }
}
```

We can refactor it into more [render-props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) way:

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<Loader loading={false}>
            { this.props.render()}
        </Loader>);
    }
}
```

And then change the test accordingly:

```
const render = () => <SomeChildComponent />;
const wrapper = shallow(
    <ParentComponent render={render} />
);
```

However, this test becomes not really a `unit` test, as it tests more then one component at once. To get rid of this dependency we can just check if `render()` is called:

```
const renderMock = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(<ParentComponent render={ renderMock } />);
expect(wrapper.find('Loader').exists()).toBeTruthy();
expect(renderMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

If your `render()` accepts some arguments you can consider using [.toHaveBeenCalledWith](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavereturnedwithvalue)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Enzyme 3.8.0 or higher you can follow this guide:

https://medium.com/@fran.villar.rosa/how-to-test-renderprops-with-enzyme-3-8-0-c079622f68ca

On your example:

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <Loader loading={false}>
                {() =>
                    <SomeChildComponent />
               }
    }
}


const wrapper = shallow(<ParentComponent />)
  .find(Loader)
  .renderProp('children')({yourPropsHere: 'example'});

expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
```

You have to import your `Loader` component in your test file.